# Loading a somewhat busy GridView and I can see text alignment happening from left to right

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When I load my `ASP.NET .Net 4.8 GridView`, even from `cache output` I can see my css happening as it aligns my cell's data from left to right. In this particular case I'm using `JQuery` to set the css based on if the cell contains a period.

Is there a way to hide the gridview so user won't see the shifting of cell content? Not a big deal, just wondering.

asp.net snippet

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('td:contains(".")').css('text-align', 'right');
    });
</script>
```

code-behind snippet

```
using MyBusinessLayer;
using MyDataLayer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyUserInterface
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Person> people = new BLL().GetPeople();
            GridView1.DataSource = people;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            
        }
    }
}

namespace MyBusinessLayer
{
    public class BLL
    {
        public List<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            DAL dal = new DAL();
            return dal.GetPeople();
        }
        
    }
}

namespace MyDataLayer
{
    public class DAL
    {
        public List<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Name1" });

            return people;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hum, first, one should attempt to "assume" or know or define the columns for this data. In other words, you can as a general rule define the layout of the GV.

I suppose in a rare case, you might be feeding the GV different data sources, and thus ahead of time you can't know (or don't want to know) ahead of time the columns involumed. GV has formatting for currency, date etc, and thus if you can layout the gv, then that is far perferred.

However, lets assume we don't know the columns.

So, say this GV:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="40%" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

Our code to load can be this:

```
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4DB))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
                new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Firstname, LastName, HotelName, NightRate, Nights, Price, 
                                Active FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName",conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, some of those columns are number(s), so use the row data bind event:

Hence:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // for any number type, right just
        foreach (TableCell OneCol in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            double dummy = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(OneCol.Text, out dummy))
            {
                OneCol.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And thus any column - even those without decimal point will right justify

results:

[image]